# Javascript Typedef Error when using parameters

Tags: javascript, closures, javascript-objects

What am I doing wrong, and how can one pass variables to a different function within the same wrapping variable/function.

Example:

```
function customFunctionWrap(){
    this.myVar1 = 0;    
    this.getCurrentPosition = function(){
        if (navigation.geolocation) { 
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){});         
        }
    }, 

    this.doSomething = function(){ // Works
        //Do something, return 
        this.callWithParams(); //Works
    }, 

    //If I remove passing in 'value1',calling it elsewhere works
    this.doSomethingWithParams = function(value1){ 
        //Use value1

        //Return 
    }, 

    this.callWithParams = function(){
        var value1 = 'xyz';         //Is a variable that changes based on some DOM element values and is a dynamic DOM element
        this.doSomethingWithParams(value1);  //THROWS TYPEDEF ERROR: this.doSomethingWithParams is not a function 
         this.getCurrentPosition(); 
    }

}; 

    var local = new customFunctionWrap();
    local.doSomething();                  //WORKS
```

I know there is another way to do it and then directly use customFunctionWrap.callWithParams(), but am trying to understand why the former approach is erroring out.

```
var customFunctionWrap = {
   myVar1 : 0, 
   callWithParams : function(){

    }
}
```

Comment: That's totally wrong. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Edited question to what works as long as there are no argument/parameter passed in the  call(argument) doesn't work but call() works in the first example. Why does the call(argument) not work. Not very clear with IIFEs that is the part I'm trying to figure out correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What JS sees:

```
var customFunctionWrap = (some function)()
```

returned function is fired, because the last (), so it has to yield/return something, otherwise, like in your code it is "returning" undefined.

So your given code does not work.

The very first fix is to delete last 2 characters from

```
var customFunctionWrap = (some function)()
```

to make it return constructor.

Comment: ` if (navigation.geolocation) { 
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){});         
        }`

Comment: navigation and navigator are defined?

Comment: yes they are defined, but I am not even hitting that part of the code yet - not calling it yet. The error is when I call myFun(parameter), works if I just call myFun()

Comment: Thank you that fixed most of the issues I had. I also had some issues with the error callback for navigator.geolocation.. And yes, navigator was to be used, not navigation. Thanks for observing!